# Is it to worth to define `undefined and null` to function parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript

In some sample code I see `undefined` and `null` as a function parameter with pipe as shown below.

```
print(param: string | undefined) {
  console.log(param);
}
```

so my question is that is it worth to define `undefined` and `null` as a param type along with `string`(or any data type)? because string itself can be `null` or `undefined`.

in case I remove `undefined` from function parameter then it behave same.

```
print(param: string) {
  console.log(param);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right for that `undefined` and `null` can be assigned to `string` with default compiler settings.

However typescript supports the option `strictNullChecks` which means exactly this, that `null` and `undefined` are no longer assignable yo any type. This is when it makes sense to explicitly add `undefined` to still allow the caller to pass in a potentially `null` or `undefined` value.

You can read more on the topic [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html)

Answer (score 2):

When you're using the `--strictNullChecks` flag, typescript's compiler doesn't allow you to assign `null` or `undefined` to variable if it doesn't enabled they (the code, for example, `var s: string = null` won't compile, but the code `var s: string | null = null` will compile). This flag is for prevent mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the things that you want to do with that, the majority of people use that to declare optional parameters, if in some case you get a parameter that you don't need for your code, you could use that, but I suggest this way:

```
print (param? : string) {
 console.log(param);
}
```

That's the way for optional params.

A simple example for that is something to generate a password, e.g.

```
checkPassword (password? : string) {
 if (!password) {
   password = this.somethingToGeneratePassword();
 }
}
```